# headerLeft is not working in reactNavigation V3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have checked previous answers and tried different methods but still not working. Only if I use static navigationOptions inside the screen it works

I tried using defaultNavigationOptions but not working also navigationOptions on its on is not working

```
TIMETABLE = createStackNavigator(
    {
        timetable: {
            screen: timetable,
            defaultNavigationOptions: {
                title: i18n.t('TIMETABLE'),
                headerStyle,
                headerTitleStyle,
                headerLeft: (
                    <Button
                        title="oi"
                        color="#fff"
                    />
                )
            }
        }
    }
);

the above does not work and neither the below code: 

TIMETABLE = createStackNavigator(
    {
        timetable: {
            screen: timetable,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: i18n.t('TIMETABLE'),
                headerStyle,
                headerTitleStyle,
                headerLeft: (
                    <Button
                        title="oi"
                        color="#fff"
                    />
                )
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Expecting to see a button with the title 'oi' on the left of the stack navigator header, but no button appears.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it because your `button` background is white?

```js
               navigationOptions: {
                title: i18n.t('TIMETABLE'),
                headerLeft: (
                  <View style={{paddingLeft: 20}}>
                    <Button
                        title="oi"
                        color="black"
                    />
                    </View>
                )
            }
```

[Example of button execution](https://snack.expo.io/Hkc8ZeF7B)

Comment: Not really, my header color is dark blue and I cannot even see the button Body

Answer (score 0):

### Do like this

```
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Text style={{color: '#000', fontSize: 18}}>Hey There</Text>
          ),
          headerLeftContainerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#fff'},
```

### or,

```
          headerLeft: () =>{return (
            <Text style={{color: '#000', fontSize: 18}}>Hey There</Text>
          )},
          headerLeftContainerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#fff'},
```